# How to use groupby and .loc to filter dataframe sequentially

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I have a large dataframe that contains information about food items. For example:

```
     Year    Journal    Subscription    Known_author
0    2014       A            1               1
1    2014       A            1               0 
2    2014       B            0               1
3    2014       C            1               0
4    2015       A            1               1
5    2015       B            1               1
6    2015       C            0               1
7    2015       D            0               0
```

I want to be able to group by year and create a table that contains (1) the number of unique journals per year, (2) number of unique journals that have a subscription, and (3) number of unique journals that have a subscription and a known author.

This would be the table that I am looking for in this scenario:

```
Year   (1) Column         (2) Column      (3) Column
2014       3                   2               1
2015       4                   2               2
```

I have used:

(1) `df.groupby('Pub_Date_Year')['Journal'].agg('nunique')` for the first column

(2) `df.loc[(df['Subscription']==1)&(df['Year']==2014),'Journal'].agg(['nunique']).values[0]`

(3) `df.loc[(df['Subscription']==1)&(df['Known_author']==1)&(df['Year']==2014),'Journal'].agg(['nunique']).values[0]`

However, I would want this table to be created in one go, I'm assuming using groupby, aggregate and some sort of lambda function. The ultimate idea is to automate this process as we get more data in, and not have to rely on manually changing the year in the df.loc code.

Is there a way this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you guessed, you need to use `groupby` plus `apply` with a custom function.

```
def grouping(x):
    journal_uniq = x['Journal'].nunique()
    journal_subs = x.groupby('Journal').apply(lambda d : d['Subscription'].sum() > 0).sum()
    journal_author = x.groupby('Journal').apply(lambda d : ((((d['Subscription'] == 1) & (d['Known_author'] == 1)).sum()) > 0)).sum()
    return pd.Series([journal_uniq, journal_subs, journal_author])

ddf = df.groupby('Year').apply(grouping)
```

Using your sample input, this will return:

```
      0  1  2
Year         
2014  3  2  1
2015  4  2  2
```

More details on the function:

- `journal_uniq` is the value in the 1st column. It counts the unique values in column `'Journal'` using `nunique`, you already did this step.
- `journal_subs` is the value in the 2nd column. Since you want the unique journals, you need to group on `'Journal'` too and check if the sum of `'Subscription'` is greater than zero. The second `sum` function sums the number of `True` values (True are casted to 1, False to 0).
- `journal_author` is the value in the 3rd column. The logic is the same for 2nd column, but a bit more complex since you need to check that both `'Subscription'` and `'Known_author'` column are equal to 1 at the same row.
- The returned `pandas.Series` is a row of the final dataframe.

Comment: Thank you for the script and the explanation! I've also slowly broken it down into my notebook and it makes perfect sense.